# How to use Data Category Visibility in a data category picklist that generated from code

Tags: apex, picklist, articles, schema, data-category

Problem description:

I have a picklist for data categories which I am generating dynamically from apex code, currently because I'm doing it from code using *Schema.describeDataCategoryGroups* and *Schema.describeDataCategoryGroupStructures* I get all data categories and sub categories, but each user can see different categories set by his profile Data Category Visibility.

Solution help needed:

I am searching for a way to map data categories relatively to user Data Category Visibility in his profile, so I can populate pick-list values properly. In order to do it I need  a way to get the Data Category Visibility of each profile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using [getTopCategories()](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_class_Schema_DescribeDataCategoryGroupStructureResult.htm) you get it by user profile visibility:
"Returns a Schema.DataCategory object, that contains the top categories visible depending on the user's data category group visibility settings."